# How to transform c# Point to c# Region?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I want to make an exact duplicate of Photoshop Magic Stick or paint tool.
Maybe I should custom a regiondata,but how is it to be done?

Comment: start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 0):

Point to region? I can only think for this:

```
Point point1 = new Point(60, 10);
Point point2 = new Point(100, 150);
Region region1 = new Region(new Rectangle(point1.X, point1.Y, point2.X-point1.X, point2.Y-point1.Y));
```